# Batch file formatting?

Tags: batch-file

Why does this work:

```
set /a num = %random% %% 5 + 1

if %num% == 1 set map=cs_assault
if %num% == 2 set map=cs_italy
if %num% == 3 set map=cs_office
if %num% == 4 set map=de_aztec
if %num% == 5 set map=de_bank

srcds -game csgo -port 27016 -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_casual +map %map%
```

But this doesn't?

```
set /a num = %random% %% 5 + 1

if %num% == 1 set map = cs_assault
if %num% == 2 set map = cs_italy
if %num% == 3 set map = cs_office
if %num% == 4 set map = de_aztec
if %num% == 5 set map = de_bank

srcds -game csgo -port 27016 -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_casual +map %map%
```

I can't seem to wrap my brain around this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second example is creating a variable called "map " not "map" and the value
" de_mapname" not "de_mapname"

So if you were to change

```
srcds -game csgo -port 27016 -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_casual +map %map%
```

to

```
srcds -game csgo -port 27016 -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_casual +map %map %
```

It would work, otherwise there is no variable `map`.

Comment: That seems strange to me, though, because the spaces are allowed on either side of the equal sign here:

`set /a num = %random% %% 5 + 1`

So why does it work there, but not below?

Comment: Because that is a expression, different syntax.

Comment: It hurts my brain. Not only that, but it looks ugly, and I hate ugly code.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I guess. You could just make map `%map : =%` to clean the variable, but that looks a lot uglier.  Batch isn't pretty.  Is your question answered?